# Java application gets crash abruptly

Tags: java

I have created java application which has bidirectional communication on same serial port.
I have created Jar file for bidirectional communication and that jar file is getting executed from java application.I am using javax.comm.SerialPort object for serial port communication in jar file.
some times this application gets crashed abruptly.The Occurrence of crash is random(after 4,5 days or it may occur 2-3 times in a day)
I am using java 1.6 update 16.Also MAcfee antivirus is installed on the same machine.
I have excluded the folder of jar file which i am accessing from antivirus scan.

Can anybody help me in finding route cause?

Comment: Does it crash based on an event? Or is it entirely random?

Comment: Hello Josh,It is entirely random crash.

Comment: How do you know it is entirely random? Isn't there an error message when it crashes?

Comment: Define "crash". If an exception is thrown, it will generally tell you what file and what line of that file contained the failure, and the call stack (if you print it out, and you should) will tell you how you got to that point.

Comment: I am logging errors in text files in catch block.Also i have checked in windows event viewer. I did not get any logs or error message.

Comment: info:my application is using third party jar file .Comm.jar,win32com.dll,javax.comm.properties

Comment: See if you are running out of memory , might be assigning variables i endless loop or something filling up your jvm .

Comment: keshlam: my application gets closed abruptly or may be java.exe getting killed. I am not able to figure out whether it is an environmental issue or not.I have put some logs in text file in catch block but i did not see any exception in log files.

Comment: i am using VisualVM to monitor the application.Can anybody tell me that using VisualVM to finding the route cause wil work or not?

Comment: Try updating java. It could be a bug if no log is available.

Comment: Hi , i am adding event listener   [code:  serialPort.addEventListener(this);] do i need to remove event listener before closing comport and streams .Can anybody help me on this